# Azure EventHub : How can I get list of partition keys for an existing EventHub

Tags: partitioning, partition, azure-eventhub

I have an Azure EventHub which already has records. I need to get a list of unique partition keys within this EventHub. This I need to use for a specific custom logic in my processor/consumer. Appreciate any suggestions or workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're possibly conflating a `partition id` and `partition key`; the former is a core concept for Event Hubs and can be queried using the SDKs for any of the supported languages, the command line, or the REST interface directly.  An example for the .NET client library can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/samples/Sample01_HelloWorld.cs).

The Event Hubs service does not persist or expose the partition keys used when publishing an event.  When an event batch with partition key is published, the service produces a hash based on that key and uses that hash value to select a partition to which the event should be routed.  The same key is guaranteed to produce the same hash and route to the same partition.  Since the hash value is stable for a given key and the key itself does not have meaning to the service, it is calculated on-demand.

In your case, it sounds like you'd like to understand what key was used when the event was published in your downstream consumer as you're reading it from the service.  I'd recommend using the `Properties` bag of the event to hold hold onto the key that you've chosen and associate it with the event.

The `Properties` are intended to hold arbitrary data that is meaningful to your application and bundle it with your event as it passes through the system.  An example of including custom metadata in the `Properties` using the .NET client library can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/samples/Sample08_PublishEventsWithCustomMetadata.cs).

Comment: Thanks. I am actually looking specifically for list of partition keys and not the partition ids. While creating the Eventhub record it is possible to specify the partition key. This can be a grouping mechanism say country or state. Then the Eventhub will have a number of records which may be stored in partitions based on these specified keys. Of course it is not guaranteed which partition holds which keys but generally all records with the same key would be in the same partition.

Comment: Knowing the list of partition keys would let me determine the number of unique countries/states  without having to loop thru all the records in the eventhub.

Comment: Understood; in a nutshell, the service does not track that information, you will need to do so yourself.   Further context and details start in the second paragraph of my answer.